# How to Remove menus icons in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

How to remove bottom menu or quick links style before ul list icon in Joomla?

[image: bottom menus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
ul.menuclassname li { list-style: none; display: inline; }
```